# How to Right Align Numbers in GTK# Spin Button?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

Can anyone tell me how to right align the numbers in a GTK# spinbutton control?

I can't for the life of my figure out how it works there. The documentation is sparse, and I'm just drawing a blank after numerous attempts.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a subclass of `Gtk.Entry` - you should just be able to set the `Xalign` property to false.

Comment: Thanks. Found that it can't be done in Stetic and must be done in code. (Was up late and my brain had fallen out. Coffee this morning helped debug the foggy brain.) spinbutton1.Xalign = 1.0f;