# Right align in spin button (gtk/C)

Tags: c, gtk, gimp

I am writing GIMP plugin in C and need to right align a number inside a GTK+ spin button.

I found out about `gtk_button_set_alignment()` but nothing like `gtk_spin_button_set_alignment()` seems to exist.

How can be this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect [the class hierarchy](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSpinButton.html#GtkSpinButton.object-hierarchy), and notice that `GtkSpinButton` inherits from [`GtkEntry`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html).

The latter has the method [`gtk_entry_set_alignment()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-set-alignment), which is what I would recommend, that really should work.

There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284994/how-to-right-align-numbers-in-gtk-spin-button) which is in C# but almost a dupe. Not sure what "false" means in that answer though, the [`xalign` property](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry--xalign) is a `float` in the C API.

Comment: @user2389519 Great! Please click the check mark and accept the answer if you feel it helped.

Comment: I saw the other question but was not able to find out how/where to set xalign here...